# JWS new version detected on server ip change (codebase using domain name)

Tags: java, java-web-start

I'm using a domain name in the "codebase" field of a JNLP file, and every time the server IP changes (the domain is updated, by the way) the client detects a new version of the app at startup and downloads it.

Although the app hasn't changed at all the change is detected only because of the IP change, and I'd like to know whether there's a way to prevent this to happen or not.